# Does delete[] free correctly in this code?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider the following way of working with a dynamically allocated two-dimensional array (for some reason, this way does not appear among the replies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936687/2725810)):

```
const int nRows = 2, nCols = 3;
int (*arr)[nCols] = (int(*)[nCols])(new int[nRows * nCols]);
arr[1][1] = 2;
std::cout << arr[1][1] << endl;
delete[] arr;
```

Does `delete[]` in the last line free the memory correctly in this case?

Comment: Wherever you got "this way", it's wrong. The first sign it's broken is that cast, Ultimately you're not type-proper in freeing what you allocated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour; the type of the argument to `delete` must have the same type as the result of the corresponding `new`.

You could improve the code with:

```
int (*arr)[nCols] = new int[nRows][nCols];
```

(or even `auto *arr =` ...) in which case the same delete expression would be correct. Having to use a cast is generally a sign you've taken a mis-step.

Comment: I believe `arr[1][1] = 2;` also violates strict aliasing in OP's code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat IMO it doesn't although that might be a topic for another question. Also it could be argued (quite well) that the result of the cast is not well-defined